# Proving whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I've updated my proof to be complete now, edited for proof-verification!

---

We know that for the partial sums with even an uneven terms, the following holds:

$S_{2N}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1} -\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{6} +\frac{1}{5}-\dots+\frac{1}{2N-1}$
$= \frac{1}{2\times1} +\frac{1}{4\times3} + \frac{1}{6\times5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N(2N-1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}$

We may rewrite the series in pairs as we know  it will have an even amount of terms.

$S_{2N+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1} -\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{3}-\dots+\frac{1}{2N-1} -\frac{1}{2N+2}$
$=\frac{1}{2\times1} +\frac{1}{4\times3} + \frac{1}{6\times5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N(2N-1)} - \frac{1}{2N+2} = \sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{2N+2}$

As $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we know that $n\geq1$ so:

$n\geq1 \iff 3n\geq3 \iff 3n^2\geq3n \iff 3n^2-3n\geq0 \iff 4n^2-2n \geq n^2+n$

So: $2n(2n-1)\geq n(n+1) \iff \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}\leq \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ for all $n\geq1$.

As the series of the latter sequence converges, we can conclude, by the comparison, test that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}$ converges.

Suppose it converges to $s$, then we know $^{\lim S_{2N}}_{N\to\infty} = s$ and thus $\lim_{N\to\infty}[S_{2N+1}] = s - (\lim_{N\to\infty}[\frac{1}{2N+2}]) = s-0 = s.$ As the partial sums ending with even and uneven terms both converge to the same limit, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}$  converges. $\tag*{$\Box$}$

---

Comment: Are you familiar with the alternating series test?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: I am, but in this case I was not allowed to use it

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991254/let-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n13-n6-1n-does-it-converge-or-doe), it seems closely related.

Comment: But the terms in $S_{2N}$ can be made positive: $(2\times 1)^{-1}+\cdots$, we can deal with comparison test or something similar like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2k(2k-1)}\leq\sum_{k=2}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2k(2k-(k/2))}=\dfrac{1}{3}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}<\dfrac{1}{3}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}<\infty,
\end{align*}
so $\{S_{2N}\}$ is convergent, so is $\{S_{2N+1}\}$ because $\lim_{N}(S_{2N+1}-S_{2N})=0$ (so they have the same limit). Then $\{S_{N}\}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 3):

As you computed, it's the alternating harmonic series in a different order. In fact the first N terms are just the first N terms of the alternating harmonic series permuted (*edit: with an extra term which decays like 1/N in case N is odd*), so the sequence of partial sums is the same.

Comment: Since the alternating harmonic series isn't absolutely convergent, its terms can form any limit when summed in a suitable order. The crucial point is that the first $2k$ terms are as in the usual ordering and give $\ln 2$ as the sum, and the odd-numbered terms change the total by an amount that $\to 0$.

Comment: @J.G. Not if the permutation fixes every partial sum

Comment: By definition, to fix every partial sum would be to have the same permutation as before! (That holds for the sequence $S_{2n}$, but not $S_n$.) In this case the permutation is "similar enough" that the sum of the first $n$ terms is changed by a null sequence.

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean by "have the same permutation as before"?  Also what's a null sequence? All I'm saying is that if a permutation $\sigma: \{a_1,a_2,...\} \rightarrow \{a_1,a_2 ,... \} $ fixes set-wise every $\{a_1,..., a_n\}$, then $\sum a_k = \sum \sigma (a_k)$

Comment: A null sequence is one of limit $0$. Your definition of a fixed permutation is one that requires all $a_i$ to be unchanged; on the original definition of $S_n$, your setwise definition only works for even $n$.

Comment: I didn't define anything. Also, "fixes set-wise" does not mean "restricts to the identity on the set."

Comment: @J.G. oh you're saying that you get an extra -1/(n+1) for odd partial sums. yes I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n-(-1)^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigg[\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n-(-1)^{n}}-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\Bigg]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}-(-1)^{n}n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$$

Now the left series converges by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$, and the right series converges by [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 1):

Let:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n-(-1)^n}$$

Note that:

- for $n=2k-1 \implies a_{2k-1}=\frac{1}{2k}$
- for $n=2k \implies a_{2k}=\frac{1}{2k-1}$
- for $n=2k+1 \implies a_{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2k+2}$
- for $n=2k+2 \implies a_{2k+2}=\frac{1}{2k+1}$

Therefore we can reorder the series $a_n\to b_n$ in such way that $b_n$ is monolitically decreasing, since:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nb_n<+\infty$$

the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$s =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n} = $$
$$ -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{4}  + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots $$
$$\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \cdots\right)$$
$$ \sum_{k =1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}\right) - \sum_{k =1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$
$$ \sum_{k =1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$

> $$s = \ln(2)$$

And the series converges to the natural logarithm.

See the special case of the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) 
 $$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$
Setting $x=1$ in the Mercator series yields the [Alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series)

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\ln(2)$$

Comment: You can't reorder the terms if you dont know the series converges absolutely.

Comment: Hi Lucas, could you give me more details or an example about your observation? I do not see the error in my answer. Thank.

Comment: It's strange, I do not find much in English on the subject. In English I think it would be called summability theory. Basically, if we consider a series that converges but does not converge absolutely (it is the case here), by changing the order of indexing, we can make sure that the series converges to any real chosen (it's quite surprising ).